# What am I doing wrong with my probability equation?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have these 3 values given to me

```
f(0) = P(X = 0) = 0.592704
f(2) = P(X = 2) = 0.064512
f(3) = P(X = 3) = 0.004096
```

I found f(1) by 1- sum of all other decimal numbers (f(1) = .338, I then need to then find E(x) and Var(x), for E(X) I know you take sum of xf(x) for x=0 to 3, I do .592 + .338 + .064 + .004 and it says I am wrong? and then for the Var(x) I am unsure why I am getting incorrect results, I am doing the deviation of the numbers. I get .479, .521, 1.521 and 2.521 and then the deviation squared to get .229, .271, 2.31, 6.35 and then I multiply by the probabilities and add everything up (to get the variance) and I get .401 but it says I am wrong, I dont know whether I am missing something important? But i am almost positive i am solving it correctly, any help on that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability that X equals 1, as you correctly noted:

```
> 1-.593-.0645-.0041
[1] 0.3384
```

The expectation is not just the sum of the probabilities. It's the sum of the probabilities times the values of X at each probability:

```
> mu=0*.593+1*.338+2*.0645+3*.0041
> mu
[1] 0.4793
```

Variance is the expected value of X-mu, squared. So subtract mu from each X, square it, and then sum over the probabilities.

```
> (0-mu)^2*.593+(1-mu)^2*.338+(2-mu)^2*.0645+(3-mu)^2*.0041
[1] 0.4030796
```